# Is it better to do a bachelors in general Computer Science or in a subfield focused degree?

Tags: computer-science, career-path, industry, bachelor

I'm in a dilemma between whether to do bachelors in general Computer Science or a specialization in it. These specializations include Artificial intelligence, Cyber security, Data Science, and Software Engineering.

From what I've heard, it's better to do a general CS degree in order to form a strong basis, but I'm also hearing it's better to do specialization as the industry is getting oversaturated and it's better to have specialized knowledge.

I'd really like the insight of someone who has a good idea about the industry. If it helps I have profound interest in Artificial Intelligence; but I'm swayed away from a bachelors in AI for the aforementioned reasons.
An elaborate explanation is appreciated.

Comment: ‘Is it better …?’ What does _better_ look like to you? Do you have a goal in mind?

Comment: A bachelor’s degree isn’t particularly specialized regardless of what you call it.

Comment: I don't have a concrete goal in mind; I just want to be financially stable in the future while also pursuing my interests. I've familiarized myself with machine learning stuff, but I'm unsure if I can make it a career goal considering the volatility of the industry and whether there will be a demand for what I do

Comment: If there's a way for you to work through a few summer internships, you might end up with a bit better insight into some of the opportunities in industry. And in the meantime, learn to code, nonstop.

Comment: Where is it possible to do a "specialized" CS degree at the bachelor's level in those subfields? General CS seems pretty necessary in all of them.

Comment: @Buffy, these kind of specialized degrees [which I don't think are a good idea] exist in Australia for example. Maybe England as well, though I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The best condition of the tech industry can only be described as changing, in the last 10 years many trends have came and gone. The only way to build a successful career in the industry is to have experience in the field. The best advice I can give is don't run after degrees. Get a basic degree in computer science and develop your skill set and adapt the ever changing nature of the industry.